# Descending Selection Sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have wrote a selection sort method to **descend** the numbers of the array. The header of the method is:

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] num) { ... }
```

In the main class, I prompted the user to enter he size of the array and the numbers inside the array, but I ran into compiler error that it didn't except how I wrote the method with the array in the main class.

```
    int sorted = selectionSort(arrayNum[arraySize]);
    System.out.println("Sorted numbers of the array are: " + sorted);
```

I know there is a problem because of the **int sorted** isn't the same with the array **int[] arrayNum**, and there is a problem with my usage of the method.

What is the correct way to write the array of the main class in that method?

Comment: what is the compiler error exactly?

Comment: you have void return type why do you assign to int sorted

Answer (score 2):

The working code in this [online compiler ide](https://www.codiva.io/p/be4128fd-3a65-4b1a-8bb0-721fa5107369).

The basic issue is, the selection sort implantation you probably implemented or took from book is implanted in a typical way where the the sort method modifes the input array. 
So just pass the array, the array will not contain the sorted elements.
Note: in the example, I have just used the existing sorting method that sorts ascending order. Fix that method with your implementation.

```
int[] num = { 4, 8,2,1,6};
selectionSort(num);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
```

https://www.codiva.io/p/be4128fd-3a65-4b1a-8bb0-721fa5107369

Comment: Show your code, do not post a link to it. If you post a link it is much less likely to be useful to someone else who has the same problem later.

Comment: Thanks. Added the code sample here. I hope I get back an upvote :)